# How to load images and description for hotels using travel advisor api

Tags: javascript

```
let cities=['Delhi', 'Goa', 'Hyderabad', 'Kolkata', 'Chennai', 'Agra', 'Jaipur', 'Bengaluru'];
let cities_data=[];
for(let i=0; i<cities.length; i++) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", `https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/locations/search?query=${cities[i]}`, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "39cb6e4388mshab83d1703c8651dp1b3aa8jsnc2cb8092bfbe");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com");
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            cities_data.push(JSON.parse(this.response).data[0].result_object.photo.images.large.url);
        }
    }
    
}
console.log(cities_data);
```

I have to load the images to my html page

```
<div class="cityImage" >
            <div class="image"><a href="list.html"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/15/33/fe/a2/new-delhi.jpg"><div class="cityName">Delhi</div></a></div>
            <div class="image"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/15/33/fc/f0/goa.jpg"><div class="cityName">Goa</div></div>
            <div class="image"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0f/98/f7/df/charminar.jpg"><div class="cityName">Hyderabad</div></div>
            <div class="image"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/15/33/fe/ac/kolkata-calcutta.jpg"><div class="cityName">Kolkata</div></div><br>
            <div class="image"><a href="list.html"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/15/4d/46/b8/chennai-madras.jpg"><div class="cityName">Chennai</div></a></div>
            <div class="image"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/15/33/fc/fc/agra.jpg"><div class="cityName">Agra</div></div>
            <div class="image"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/10/a3/3b/8a/screenshot-2017-09-12.jpg"><div class="cityName">Jaipur</div></div>
            <div class="image"><img class="city_img" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0c/d2/2f/7a/palace-from-the-outside.jpg"><div class="cityName">Bengaluru</div></div><br>
        </div>
```

Need to replace all these images with travel advisor api images inside the javascript file

Answer (score 0):

```
const {data:{results}} = apiResponse
```

Now you will get **results** and **results** is an array of obj and now just loop over **results** and get **detailsV2** and **image** property, Destructure  the detailsV2 property `{names,geocode,contact} = detailsV2` and get access the 3 object where you can find details that you need and now get access Image property just Destructure **image** `{photo: {photoSize}} = image` and access **photoSize** property **photoSize** is an array of objects where every object is the different size of the images access the URL property within **photoSize** and now just choose image size that you need and use it.

I hope I understand your question well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `XMLHttpRequest()` can be a little bit tricky as you need to code a lot ! so to solve this use `fetch()` api built in js .... To get images from api you need to first make an ajax call > get data > display image . See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) guide for information about fetch API

See =>

**HTML**

```
<div class="cityImage">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="list.html">
      <img class="city_img" />
      <div class="cityName">
        Delhi
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="list.html">
      <img class="city_img" />
      <div class="cityName">
        Goa
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="list.html">
      <img class="city_img" />
      <div class="cityName">
        Hyderabad
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="list.html">
      <img class="city_img" />
      <div class="cityName">
        Kolkata
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="list.html">
      <img class="city_img" />
      <div class="cityName">
        Chennai
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {
    margin: 20px 10%;
  }
  .image {
    margin: 40px 0;
    background: #eaeaea;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .image  a {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3b2944;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
@keyframes shimmer {
   0%{
     background-position: -500px 0 ;
   }
   100%{
     background-position: 500px 0 ;
     
   }
  }
  .city_img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    object-fit: cover;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: linear-gradient( to right , #dbdbdb 20%, #d8d8d8 40% , #dbdbdb 60%, #dbdbdb 80%);
    animation: shimmer 2s infinite linear;
  }
```

**Js**

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".image")
let cities = ['Delhi', 'Goa', 'Hyderabad', 'Kolkata', 'Chennai'];

let cities_data = [];

async function data(city) {
  let response = await fetch(`https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/locations/search?query=${city}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "x-rapidapi-key": "39cb6e4388mshab83d1703c8651dp1b3aa8jsnc2cb8092bfbe",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
  });
  response = await response.json();
  return await response;
}

// Looping through each city
cities.forEach(city => {
  data(city)
  .then(res=> {
    console.log(res);
    images.forEach(img=> {
      let content = img.querySelector('.cityName').textContent.trim();
      if (content === city) {
        img.querySelector("img").src = res.data[0].result_object.photo.images.large.url;
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(err=> {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: @asdf_lkjhI added a little bit of CSS to add a shimmer effect before the image source is loaded just to make it look fine you can do a lot more !

Answer (score 0):

The URLs of all the images are present in the URL key of the response. You can access them something like this `res.data[0].result_object.photo.images.large.url`.

If you want to display an image with the dynamic URL (URL coming from API response), you can do this something like this.

```
export default function App() {
  const url =
    "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1418907808930611205/Ri1UEOZm_400x400.jpg";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={url} />
    </div>
  );
}
```